# Can I $nin on the current projection in an aggregate pipeline

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I have a directional graph to relate people to people, people to children, and people to pets. The relationship model looks like this:

```
module.exports = mongoose.model('Relationship', {
  sourcePerson: {type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Person'},
  targetPerson: {type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Person'},
  targetChild: {type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Child'},
  targetPet: {type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Pet'},
  relationshipStatus: {
    type: String,
    enum: enums.relationshipStatus
  }
});
```

The primary reason I **am not** using child documents via arrays off of the people is because the maintenance for that type of data model is too high and too strict. I know those statements contrast a little.

You see, if a couple is married then assumptions are made when adding relationships and the **logical** model becomes a bit more strict, but if they aren't then relationships are very loose and must be for the use case.

So, let's consider 3 people:

```
_id     firstName     lastName
1       Bob           Smith
2       Jane          Smith
3       Billy         Bob
```

and their relationships:

```
sourcePerson     targetPerson     relationshipStatus
1                2                M
2                1                M
```

Take note that `3`, `Billy Bob`, does not have a relationship to any people.

---

Now, I have a query I'm building that projects a profile for people. Specifically, are they married, do they have pets, and do they have children.

Thus far I've constructed the following `aggregate`:

```js
db.people.aggregate([

{
    $match: {
        '_id': {
            $in: db.relationships.distinct('sourcePerson', {
                relationshipStatus: {
                    $eq: 'M'
                }
            })
        }
    }
},

{
    $project: {
        firstName: 1,
        lastName: 1,
        profile: {
            married: {
                $literal: true
            }
        }
    }
},

{
    $match: {
        '_id': {
            $in: db.relationships.distinct('sourcePerson', {
                targetPet: {
                    $ne: null
                }
            })
        }
    }
},

{
    $project: {
        firstName: 1,
        lastName: 1,
        profile: {
            married: 1,
            pets: {
                $literal: true
            }
        }
    }
},

{
    $match: {
        '_id': {
            $in: db.relationships.distinct('sourcePerson', {
                targetChild: {
                    $ne: null
                }
            })
        }
    }
},

{
    $project: {
        firstName: 1,
        lastName: 1,
        profile: {
            married: 1,
            pets: 1,
            children: {
                $literal: true
            }
        }
    }
}

])
```

The immediate problem I have is how can I perform a `$nin` on the `_id` of the `Person` using what I'm going to call the "current projection."

Specifically what I mean is this. If we take this snippet:

```js
db.people.aggregate([

{
    $match: {
        '_id': {
            $in: db.relationships.distinct('sourcePerson', {
                relationshipStatus: {
                    $eq: 'M'
                }
            })
        }
    }
},

{
    $project: {
        firstName: 1,
        lastName: 1,
        profile: {
            married: {
                $literal: true
            }
        }
    }
}

...

])
```

At this point I have a projection of all "married people". From this projection alone I can identify those that are "not married" if I could `$nin` the current projection.

I'm not sure this is even what I want.
If there is a better overall way, I'm totally open.

Looking forward to your feedback!

Comment: Your question is hard to understand. Can you show us sample documents with expected result?

Comment: From what I can see, your problems might well rather be related to your modeling. I second user3100115's request for the sample documents and would strongly suggest providing all of the involved models and the use cases.

Comment: @user3100115 I have attempted, and will continue to attempt, to help clarify this question. Please see my edit.

Comment: @MarkusWMahlberg, please have a look at my edit and let me know your thoughts.

Comment: @MichaelPerrenoud Have to think about this, but that model seems to be less than optimal for your use cases as I have understood it. Let me get it straight: You have various symmetric and asymmetric relationships (like "married","childOf","parentOf" and alike) and want to have queries which return the subjects of a given relationship?